# Masonry + infinite scrolling isnt working

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

i have tried infinity scrolling with masonry and when i try to implement in my site, it isnt working. Can anybody help me please? When i try to do this on blank page, its working.

I dont know if there must be some CSS rule or something like that.

Thanks for any advice.

Live demo: http://www.marygate.cz/beta

Second page should be http://www.marygate.cz/beta/1.html

My javascript code:

```
var $container = $('#content');

$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.produkt',
    columnWidth: 275
  });
});

$container.infinitescroll({
  navSelector  : '#page-nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
  nextSelector : '#page-nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
  itemSelector : '.produkt',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
  loading: {
      finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
      img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
    }
  },
  // trigger Masonry as a callback
  function( newElements ) {
    // hide new items while they are loading
    var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
      // show elems now they're ready
      $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
      $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
    });
  }
);

});
```